# Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {}; Exception occured

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I'm getting this exception it's driving me crazy could anyone help? and thanks

```
error _TypeError (type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)
```

from this code

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController?> _controller = Completer();
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
  Location location = Location();
  Marker? sourcePosition, destinationPosition;
  loc.LocationData? _currentPosition;
  LatLng curLocation = LatLng(32.8945, 13.1807);
  StreamSubscription<loc.LocationData>? locationSubscription;
// تحديث الموقع

addPolyLine(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates) {
    PolylineId id = PolylineId('poly');
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      color: Colors.blue,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 5,
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

I tried to fix the problem by casting Map but honestly, I couldn't understand how to do it

defining the polylineId and polyline :

```
addPolyLine(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates) {
    PolylineId id = PolylineId('poly');
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      color: Colors.blue,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 5,
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

addPolyline is called within getdirection

```
  getDirections(LatLng dst) async {
    List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
    List<PolylineWayPoint> wayPoints = [];

    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      google_api_key,
      PointLatLng(curLocation.latitude, curLocation.longitude),
      PointLatLng(dst.latitude, dst.longitude),
      travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
      wayPoints: wayPoints,
    );

    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    } else {
      print(result.errorMessage);
    }

    addPolyLine(polylineCoordinates);
  }
```

stack call:-

> MethodChannelLocation.onLocationChanged.
> (c:\Users\MrObscure\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location_platform_interface-3.1.0\lib\src\method_channel_location.dart:146)
> _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213)
> _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153)
> _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594)
> _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339)
> _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515)
> _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620)
> _PendingEvents.schedule. (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591)
> _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40)
> _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49)

[image: stacktrace]

Comment: Please don't tag your question as [java] if it doesn't have anything to do with Java.

Comment: provide the code where you define:
PolylineId and Polyline

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `addPolyLine`?

Comment: @d-markey i have post it

Comment: That's weird, the error message hints that you're passing or assigning a `Map` (= `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` = `Map<Object?, Object?>`) where the receiver expects a `Map<String, dynamic>`. But none of the code you've posted uses a `Map` of that sort. what's the full stacktrace when the exception is raised?

Comment: @d-markey  i have posted the full stack trace